# Is there a command line utility to list available nodelets within the package path?

Tags: nodelet

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In debugging nodlet issues, and considering which nodes can be consolidated into a single process via nodelets, it would be nice to be able to simply list all available nodelets. Is there a command that does this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9839/is-there-a-command-line-utility-to-list-available-nodelets-within-the-package-path?/) by [Asomerville](https://answers.ros.org/users/351/asomerville/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2743 on 2011-04-28

Post score: 6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Now there is (since a while actually).

A first check can be done via:

```
$ rospack plugins --attrib=plugin nodelet
```

Ref: http://answers.ros.org/question/65189/nodelet-is-not-recognized-as-a-plugin/

(S: The link @tfoote provided is dead, but wouldn't be surprised, if this is the tool he talked about.)

However, this only shows you packages exporting the nodelet information.

If your nodelet is listed there, but  you are still unable to load it properly, I suggest to run the following (replace `/nodelet_manager` with the name of your nodelet manage):

```
$ rosservice call /nodelet_manager/load_nodelet "name: ''
type: 'burb'
remap_source_args: ['']
remap_target_args: ['']
my_argv: ['']
bond_id: ''"
```

This will respond with an error.

```
ERROR: service [/nodelet_manager/load_nodelet] responded with an error:
```

But in the terminal running the nodelet manager you will get the list of available nodelets. If your nodelet is missing there (or registered under a wrong name), something went wrong with your plugin registration and/or exported nodelet information.

---

Originally posted by [bit-pirate](https://answers.ros.org/users/62/bit-pirate/) with karma: 2062 on 2015-08-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There was not.  I've written one and added it to the nodelet package for the next release. You can pull it from this url in the meantime.  It's just a python script.  Download it and run it in python, or change it to executable https://code.ros.org/svn/ros-pkg/stacks/common/trunk/nodelet/scripts/declared_nodelets

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-04-28

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6